# assemble relative page.dest not working after push to the server

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

```
## version 
"version": "0.1.0",
```

### description

I am using relative page.dest  to the path of my app, it is working fine perfect in my localhost.

http://localhost:9000/application/website/index.html

`<li><a href="{{relative page.dest "application/website/index.html"}}">link 1</a></li>`

the problem is when I push this to the server: so in the server exist a folder before application for the project called: **clientwebsite**

wwww.server.com/**clientwebsite**/application/website/index.html

so when I click in the any links goes to: **wwww.server.com/application/website/index.html** (does not exist)

instead of **wwww.server.com/clientwebsite/application/website/index.html**

someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no assemble version `0.1.0`. Is this `grunt-assemble` or `assemble`? Can you show more of either the `gruntfile.js` or `assemblefile.js`? Which page is this happening in and what does the rendered `href` look like (e.g. is it an absolute or relative path)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing in the path the folder `dist/`

so I did like that:

```
<li><a href="{{relative page.dest "dist/application/website/index.html"}}">link 1</a></li>
```

now it is working perfectly